# my Django app has broken for some reason getting anerror message

Tags: django

I was cleaning out some of the unused projects on my computer and when I tried to use my latest project I get this error message

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x107b01d70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named crispy_forms
```

is this even fixable. This is a lot of work and hours for me so I hope it is

Comment: You are missing module that's being referenced inside your django project: `crispy_forms`. Either add the dependency back or remove the reference

Answer (score 0):

ImportError: No module named crispy_forms

```
pip install --upgrade django-crispy-forms
```

Add crispy_forms to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'crispy_forms',
)
```